from local to global functions in Sobolev or Bochner spaces
I am interested in finding some conditions under which functions that are locally in some Sobolev (or Bochner) spaces can be considered as part of that space globally.
More precisely I'm looking at the following three cases: $Ω$ open not bounded; $V⊂⊂Ω$; $X$ Banach
$1) u∈L_{loc}^p (Ω)$
$2) u∈W_{loc}^{1,p} (Ω)$
$3)u∈ L_{loc}^p (0,T,X)$
with the notations for norms:
$‖*‖_{0,p,V}$ for $u∈L_{loc}^p (V)$ ; $‖*‖_{1,p,V}$ for $W_{loc}^{1,p}(V)$; $‖*‖_{ε,p,X}$ for $L_{loc}^p (ε,T-ε,X)$
and using a condition of the form: $‖*‖_{0,p,V}≤c$ ;$c$ independent of $V$. I'm gonna state my case separately for each
Case 1. Assume that $u∈L_{loc}^p (Ω)$ and their exist $c=c(u,p)$ , notice that "$c$" is independent of "$V$", such that: $‖u‖_{0,p,V}≤c$. Then $u∈L^p (Ω)$
Proof: choose a sequence $V_n⊊V_{n+1}⊂⊂Ω$; so that $r_n=‖u‖_{0,p,V_n}$  is a monotoneously increasing  sequence in “R” bounded by “c” ; we know that $r_n$  is convergent, and so  it's upper limit must be $‖u‖_{0,p,Ω}$  because $Ω$ it's the smallest set containing all of $V_n$. Notice here that the case $u≡1$  is not a counter example as $‖1‖_{0,p,V}=|V|^{p^{-1}}$  which cannot be bounded.
Cas 2. Assume that $u∈W_{loc} ^{1,p} (Ω)$ and their exist $c=c(u,p)$ such that: $‖u‖_{1,p,V}≤c$. Then $u∈W^{1,p} (Ω)$
Proof: Let $Du$ be some week derivative of $u$. We can repeat the  argument for case (1) for $u$ and $Du$ to get that $u∈L^p (Ω)$ and $Du∈L^p (Ω)$  which implies that $u∈W^{1,p} (Ω)$
Case 3. before continuing I want to make sure that my statement is clear. $u∈ L_{loc} ^p (0,T,X)$ means that for all intervals $[a,b]⊂(0,T)$  we have u∈ $L_{loc} ^p (a,b,X)$. Just as in the previous cases we assume:
$u∈ L_{loc} ^p (0,T,X)$ and $‖u‖_{ε,p,X}≤c$;$c$  independent of $ε$. Then $u∈ $L^p (0,T,X)$
Proof: as in the previous cases we define $V_n=[n^{-1},T-n^{-1}]$  and it is obvious that $V_n⊊V_{n+1}⊂⊂(O,T)$. now regardless of the structure of X we have that $r_n=‖u‖_{n^{-1},p,X}$ is a monotoneously increasing  sequence in “R” bounded by “c” and again it must converge to get the desired result.
please correct me if any of the above are wrong

the overall idea of each case is the same: if the norm on compact sets is bound by the same constant then there is no point at which the function can explode, since if there is such a point we can find a compact that contains it and that contradicts the original assumption

yes, the idea is correct. It boils down to the monotone convergence theorem for the Lebesgue integral.
